# Keycloak infinite redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openid, http-status-code-403, keycloak

We are using [Keycloak 2.3.0.Final](http://blog.keycloak.org/2016/10/keycloak-230final-released.html) and we are using the Javascript adapter that is available at `/auth/js/keycloak.js`. The application that is using this adapter is an React+Redux application but that would not matter.

When we go through the auth process described in the [docs](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/securing-client-applications-guide/content/topics/oidc/javascript-adapter.html) the initial authentication is a success however when the `login-status-iframe.html` tries to refresh the token we get a 403 Forbidden.
The exact URL it's using to refresh the token `/auth/realms/<customer-realm>/protocol/openid-c…id=web-portal&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080&session_state=undefined`.
Which causes a redirect again, again and again.

I'm assuming that this breaks because `session_state` param is `undefined` but sadly I can not find any documentation on this subject.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Comment: No not really an answer, check if all the versions match. Because each version of keycloak comes with it's own keycloak.js.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if you ever found a solution, but I recently ran into this issue as well. In this [issue thread](https://github.com/dasniko/keycloak-reactjs-demo/issues/3), user djmason9's solution worked for me. Just add `checkLoginIframe: false` for the `initOptions` parameter.

Comment: This fixed a problem for me, where I'm using `onLoad: 'check-sso'` in the init options. Init was failing until I added the `checkLoginIframe: false` option.

Answer (score 6):

This almost certainly is happening because your router is in "hash" mode and using hashes for the routes.   I haven't figured out how to get the keycloak javascript adapter to work properly with hash-mode based routing, but at least you should know that's the issue you are up against.   In Vue, you can set the router to "history" mode where it works without hashes, and that solves the problem.  I am betting React has the same capability, as a work around.

(I realize this question is old, but it is surfacing at the top of duckduckgo searches and the problem still exists in current versions of the javascript adapter, so I felt like it could use an answer)

Comment: I have this same problem, I'm using Vue with vue-router. I added `mode: 'history'`, but this solution not help me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with keycloak, but your solution might not be same.

The root cause was, I had spin up multiple instances of keycloak, but the loadbalancer didn't have sticky session. So every time the request was going on different instance, the cookie was invalid on that instance, it would redirect to login, and since it is logged in the process would repeat again.

For the solution, I have brought keycloak down to one instance, and I am looking at keycloak documentation on how to run a keycloak cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the Web Origins in Keycloak configuration has no trailing slash.

Have a look at the URL which returns 403, particularly the origin parameter. The value should contain the value defined in the Web Origin in the respective client.

I faced this issue and then solved it

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue, and I solved it adding the web origin on my keycloak client to "*"